# TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertType' of undefined in Unit Test

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have initialized  `reviewSummaryContent=<any>{}`

```
 this.reviewSummaryContent = this.service.wizardData;  
  If(this.reviewSummaryContent.value.alertType==='Threshold'){
      //Code block
     }
```

setting the wizardData as

```
this.service.wizardData = {formObject: addNewAlertForm, value: addNewAlertForm.value};
```

but i am getting an error when running the test 
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'alertType' of undefined.

Comment: your initialized `reviewSummaryContent` doesnt have `value`, so its saying `value` is undefined when you try to reach `alertType`

Comment: Or, you can show us your spec file